# Como saber o último fim de semana de um mês em LUA

Tags: lua

Como obter o último fim de semana do mês de Março, para alterar a sua hora para o horário de verão.

Código paraidentificar se é o mês de Março e se é um domingo.

```
month_now=os.date("%m")
week_day=os.date("%w")
if week_day=="7" then
  print("domingo")
end
if month_now=="03" then
  print("Março")
end
```

Comment: Tenho minhas dúvidas se deveria fazer isto para saber sobre o horário de verão, não parece ser um critério confiável. Fora isto precisa saber qual é o conceito de última semana do mês. É a última que começa no mês? É a última que termina dentro dele? Que dia é usado para determinar o início da semana?

Comment: Exatamente, preciso de saber qual a ultima semana do tal mes. Pelo que vi não existe nesta linguaguem como podemos saber a semana.

Comment: Exatamente o que? Acho que você não leu o que eu escrevi e principalmente, perguntei. Sem definir o conceito vai te dar resultado errado. Embora reafirmo que provavelmente já está usando o método errado para definir horário de verão.

Comment: Qual o método melhor para utilizar?

Comment: O horário de verão é definido anualmente. Não faz o mínimo sentido essa pergunta, se for para o Brasil.

Answer (score 3):

Sem entrar no mérito do horário de verão, a função abaixo calcula o dia do último sábado de março de um dado ano.

```
function last(y)
    local t={ day=31, month=3, year=y }
    local w=os.date("*t",os.time(t)).wday
    return 31-(w%7)
end
```